# Transactions not updating DB when using container-managed(Glassfish) JPA with Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions, glassfish

How can I get JPA(via Hibernate)/Spring and my Container managed connection (via Glassfish 3.1) to play nice?

**Update**: Somehow my JPA connection seems to be buffered.  If I modify a record such that I convert its strings to upper case, then if I look it up I get a record with upper case strings. But the underlying DB does not reflect this.  Another example if I delete an entity and then try to delete it again I get an exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [db.co05in.Test#]" but again the underlying db is not updated.

Included:

- Entry code showing spring injection of TestService
- TestServiceImpl
- applicationContext.xml
- persistance.xml

**Solved**: I have no idea why but the issue was somehow caused by wiring by name? Anyways see the comments under "Service implementation code" if you experience a similar issue.

Entry code:

```
package com.aerose.partgroupmaster.action;
import com.aerose.mz.db.service.inventory.TestService;

public class DeleteTest{
    public com.aerose.mz.db.co05in.Test test; //the POJO JPA DAO
    public int id;
    private TestService testService;

    //GOOD: spring is able to inject the service 
    public void setTestService(TestService testService){
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        test = testService.retreiveTest(id);
        testService.deleteTest(test);
        return SUCCESS;
    } 
}
```

Service implementation code:

```
package com.aerose.mz.db.service.inventory;

import db.co05in.Test;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class TestImpl implements TestService{
    @PersistenceContext //needed to add this
    private EntityManager em;

    //removed this... and edited applicationContext.xml to remove the wiring
    //public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
    //    this.em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    //}

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void createTest(Test test) {
        em.persist(test);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Test retreiveTest(int id) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Test.findByIdTEST");
        query.setParameter("idTEST", id);
        return (Test) query.getResultList().get(0);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Test updateTest(Test test) {
        Test test2 = em.merge(test);
        return test2;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteTest(Test test) {
        em.remove(em.merge(test));
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>            
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aerose" />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MySQLLocalDataSource" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="co05in" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="testService" class="com.aerose.mz.db.service.inventory.TestImpl">
    <!-- following not needed -->
    <!--<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>-->
</bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="co05in" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MySQLLocalDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <class>db.co05in.Test</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with container-managed transactions you need to use `JtaTransactionManager`:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
```

As far as I understand in your case it should work fine since Hibernate is already configured to use JTA transactions via its properties.

Comment: Okay... I added the above for good measure.  I don't know if the issue is transactions or not now. If I call testService.deleteTest(test) there is no error.  If I call it a second time, I get "org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [db.co05in.Test#]".  The frustrating thing is I can see Hibernate issuing select statements to the db but it never issues any create, delete, or update queries.

Comment: +1 because I think this helped, I updated the question, and the questions applicationContext.xml to incorporate it.

Comment: @Quaternion: Note that my assumption that Hibernate is correctly configured for JTA transactions may be wrong. Also the way you obtain `EntityManager` looks strtange, try to inject it via `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: I don't know why but using @PersistenceContext now persists the data to the DB!

Comment: @Quaternion: As far as I understand, `EntityManager` obtained from `createEntityManager()` doesn't participate in Spring managed transactions at all.